# Apache/nginx 403 when uploading new files

Tags: apache, file, nginx, ftp, http-status-code-403

I've been stumped with this for a couple days now. I set up apache on my VPS and am uploading files frequently via FTP to my website. However, when I try to access those links in the browser, Apache gives me a 403 error. When I run the command "chmod 755" on the file and refresh, however, the file is accessed fine. I had the same error when I tried using nginx as my software. Thanks!

Comment: What are the permissions and owner of your freshly uploaded files via FTP? What is the apache / nginx worker, `www-data` by any mean? Is it different than the mentioned file's owner?

Comment: The permissions of new files are `-rw-------` and the permissions of working files are `-rwxr-xr-x` The owner of all files, including the working files is www (the apache worker is www-data). Thanks!

Comment: That's the reason of the 403 error, your uploaded files are owned by `www` and are readable & writable only by it, other users (like `www-data`), aren't able even to access (read) these files. You must change your ftp server configuration and either set its worker to `www-data` or set freshly uploaded file permissions to be readable by other users / groups.

Comment: How would I go about setting file permissions for new files as you suggested?

Comment: What's the name of your FTP server? Read its documentation or some totorial regarding to default file permissions, these setting must be defined in your ftp server's config file.

Comment: Oh, I'm using vsftpd, I set up the permissions and now the server is running as I want it to. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Running command "chmod 755" solved problem but if user upload new file you need to run command again and again...

So I set the default permission for newly uploaded files in **/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
file_open_mode=0755
local_umask=022
```